# Storing data in a Berkeley DB database with Python and bsddb3

Tags: python, python-3.x, berkeley-db, bsddb

I’m trying to write data to a Berkeley DB database using Python 3.5 and bsddb3. I don’t have any experience with Berkeley DB, but I like to use a time stamp as the key and some JSON data as the respective value. The following example leads to an error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import bsddb3
import time

fn = 'berkeley.db'
db = bsddb3.hashopen(fn, 'c')
t = time.time()
d = "{ data: 'foo' }"
db[t] = d
db.close()
```

The error:

```
$ python3 example.py
[...]
self.db[key] = value
TypeError: Bytes or Integer object expected for key, float found
```

Using an integer instead of `time.time()`, for instance, `db[0] = data`, doesn’t work either: `TypeError: Integer keys only allowed for Recno and Queue DB's`.

Unfortunately, there is no comprehensive documentation on how to use Berkeley DB with Python. Any suggestions regarding what I’m doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution while reading the [documentation of Kyoto Cabinet](http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/pythondoc/). The key has to be encoded as byte:

```
db[b'key'] = d
print((db.get(b'key')))
```

Running the example with the above changes will lead to an output of the stored data set:

```
$ python3 main.py
b"{ data: 'random' }"
```

Comment: use python struct module to convert python types to bytes, it keeps the lexicographic order that you might need to use if you use a btree.